# Kendo Grid MVC GridEditMode.Popup showing ID field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am trying to edit records in popup using Kendo UI Grid for MVC. I have followed the examples provided on their website. For some reason Popup is showing textbox for ID column. I would like to hide that but it has mind of its own. Help will be appreciated.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CampaignGridViewModel>()
              .Name("grid")
                .DataSource(datasource =>
                    datasource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Model(model =>model.Id(p => p.Id))
                    .Read(read => read.Action("GridGetAll", "Campaign"))
                    .Update(update => update.Action("GridEdit", "Campaign"))
                    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("GridDestroy", "Campaign"))
                )
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(o => o.Title).Title("Title Of Campaign");
                  columns.Bound(o => o.DateAdded).Format("{0:dd MMM yy}");
                  columns.Bound(o => o.CurrentStatus);
                  columns.Bound(o => o.BudgetPerDay).Format("{0:c}");
                  columns.Command(command =>
                  {
                      command.Edit();
                      command.Destroy();
                  }).Width(200);
              })
             .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
             .Pageable()
             .Sortable()
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the Id column and hide it.
Something like this :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CampaignGridViewModel>()
              .Name("grid")
                .DataSource(datasource =>
                    datasource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Model(model =>model.Id(p => p.Id))
                    .Read(read => read.Action("GridGetAll", "Campaign"))
                    .Update(update => update.Action("GridEdit", "Campaign"))
                    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("GridDestroy", "Campaign"))
                )
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Hidden();
                  columns.Bound(o => o.Title).Title("Title Of Campaign");
                  columns.Bound(o => o.DateAdded).Format("{0:dd MMM yy}");
                  columns.Bound(o => o.CurrentStatus);
                  columns.Bound(o => o.BudgetPerDay).Format("{0:c}");
                  columns.Command(command =>
                  {
                      command.Edit();
                      command.Destroy();
                  }).Width(200);
              })
             .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
             .Pageable()
             .Sortable()
            )
```

Comment: The ID textbox was still showing on the popup (even though is not shown on the table). If you are interested, I was able to remove the ID by using an EditorTemplate.

Comment: Calling `Hidden()` on the column will only hide it in the grid. When using `GridEditMode.PopUp` without a template (like Manuel Reis said), the grid will default to showing _all_ fields (hidden or not) in the editor popup.